# Various Wordpress Feeds for Same Blog

Tags: rss, feed

With http://blog.serverfault.com there are a couple of feed URLs:

- http://blog.serverfault.com/feed gives a normal feed with the full content of the post.
- http://blog.serverfault.com/rss gives only a summary and every post is listed twice

What is the proper way to control these feeds? I want to eliminate the the double posting summary feed and redirect it to the /feed feed. Should I just do this with mod_rewrite or is there a way to mange these in wordpress?

Comment: I don't see the double posts in the RSS 0.92 feed. Did you change the permalink structure recently? Perhaps your RSS reader can't see that two posts are actually the same because RSS 0.92 doesn't use a GUID.

Answer (score 2):

Main distinction between these feeds is not their content, but their type - RSS 2.0 and RSS 0.92 respectively (plus RDF and Atom feeds by the way).

If you just want to dump all RSS 0.92 feeds to site's main feed it can be handled like this:

```
remove_action( 'do_feed_rss', 'do_feed_rss' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss', 'redirect_to_rss2', 10, 0 );

function redirect_to_rss2(  ) {

    wp_redirect( site_url('feed'), 301 );
    die;
}
```

Not sure how to best handle if you want to redirect individually (for example RSS 0.92 feed of specific archive page to respective RSS 2.0 feed).